# android remove all buttons inside a view

Tags: java, android

I have a `LinearLayout` which I've looped a number of `new Button` objects into. How do I go about clearing that div correctly (eg removing all the buttons)? I've tried a number of times (unsuccessfully) to do this, but have nothing to show for it.

** edit **

I'm not sure if this helps, but in flex/AS3 I would do something like:

```
while(myView.numChildren) myView.removeChildAt(0);
```

** a little code **

```
View col1 = findViewById(R.id.col1);
for(final Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String,String>> entry : _nav.entrySet()) {
    Button item = new Button(this);
    item.setText(entry.getKey());
    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openCol2(entry);
        }
    });
    ((LinearLayout) col1).addView(item);
}

private final void openCol2(Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String,String>> entry) {
    View col2 = findViewById(R.id.col2);
    // here is where I want to clean out col2. Right before I add more buttons.

    for(int i = 0; i < _nav.size(); ++i) {
        Button item = new Button(this);
        //item.setText(entry.getKey());
        ((LinearLayout) col2).addView(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What I understood from your question, that you want to remove all views(button) from a linearlayout....if this is what you want then did you tried removeAll method ?? here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeAllViews())

Comment: @Jackon, please post your code. Also, do you use a layout file, or do you programmatically build the view?

Comment: @gopal I only see the methods of `removeCallbacks` and `removeOnLayoutChangeListener` as far as removal goes.
@Phil I just posted code to the description. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
LinearLayout col2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.col2);
col2.removeAllViews();
```

Assumption: R.id.col2 is of LinearLayout type else to make it more generic typecast it to ViewGroup. Hope this help!!!

Comment: Worked like a champ. Thanks gopal.

Comment: @gopal, if i want to add all views after .removeAllViews(); ? How can do that?